# Variable value is null when I set XML value to null

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xmldocument

My XML

```
<example>
      <ReferenceNumber xmlns="http://www.example.com/schemas/core/movement">
        <Mnemonic>LHH1</Mnemonic>
        <MovementProjectNumber>4743</MovementProjectNumber>
        <MovementVersion>5</MovementVersion>
      </ReferenceNumber>
</example>
```

// Get movement version value(5).

```
XDocument NewXML = XDocument.Parse(model.ReturnXML); // model.ReturnXML has XML as shown in above XML.
XNamespace ns = "http://www.example.com/schemas/core/movement";

var MovementVersionNew = from MovVer in NewXML.Root.Element(ns + "ReferenceNumber").Elements(ns + "MovementVersion")
                             select MovVer.Value.ToList().FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

//Fetching the XML node part to update value of MovementVersion element.

```
var MovementVersionRef = (from MovVer in NewXML.Root.Elements(ns + "ReferenceNumber")
                                               select MovVer).ToList();
```

// Setting MovementVersion value as null.

```
foreach (XElement element in MovementVersionRef.Descendants())
{
    if (!element.HasElements)
    {
        if (element.Name.ToString().Contains("MovementVersion"))
        {
            element.SetValue("");
        }
    }    
}
```

This above code will set MovementVersion value to null(in NewXML) that is correct but at the same time it is also changing value of MovementVersionNew variable(I don't want this change from 5 to null).

What can I change or use for not changing my old value because I want that value later in the code. Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The line setting MovementVersionNew must be getting re-evaluated.  Place  a breakpoint on there and look at the stack trace to see what's causing it to be run

Comment: Thanks @LordWilmore I checked and found that it is getting updated after element.SetValue("") execution. So what can be done for this?.

Comment: When you say 'after', what do you mean by that.  Do you mean as a result of the call to SetValue(""), or do you mean just from somewhere else in the code?

Comment: I mean as a result of the call to SetValue("")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `ToList()` on `MovementVersionNew`'s query.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var xmlstr = 
        @"<example>
            <ReferenceNumber xmlns='http://www.example.com/schemas/core/movement'>
            <Mnemonic>LHH1</Mnemonic>
            <MovementProjectNumber>4743</MovementProjectNumber>
            <MovementVersion>5</MovementVersion>
            </ReferenceNumber>
         </example>";

    XNamespace ns = "http://www.example.com/schemas/core/movement";
    var xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlstr);    

    var MovementVersionNew = (from MovVer in xml.Root.Element(ns + "ReferenceNumber").Elements(ns + "MovementVersion")
                                select MovVer.Value.ToList().FirstOrDefault().ToString()).ToList();

    var MovementVersionRef = (from MovVer in xml.Root.Elements(ns + "ReferenceNumber")
                                select MovVer).ToList();

    foreach (XElement element in MovementVersionRef.Descendants())
    {
        if (!element.HasElements)
        {
            if (element.Name.ToString().Contains("MovementVersion"))
            {
                element.Value = String.Empty;
            }
        }
    }

    MovementVersionNew.ForEach(Console.WriteLine); //Prints "5"
    MovementVersionRef.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

}
```

Comment: I tested this code before answering - and it works for me.

Comment: Can you just paste that code here So I can verify. Because in my case select MovVer.ToList() is not working (error:- 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Thanks

Comment: @JohnL Thank you So much from the bottom of my heart. Code is working now after checking your update answer.

Comment: @TejasThakor can I just check that you understand why this has worked?

Comment: @LordWilmore I have changed MovementVersionNew(add tolist()) and change -> element.Value = String.Empty;

Comment: @TejasThakor The Linq statement that you built up is a query that is run each and every time you read from it, so if you query the Count() then it runs once, if you read ElementAt(n) then it runs again, if you check for the existance of a value it runs again ...  So in your case, every time you checked the value it was actually re-running that query at the time you checked.  This is 'resolved' by calling ToList() on the query, which enumerates the result and stores it as an actual collection rather than a query.